# Search query over multiple indices find no hits when suggestions fail

Tags: elasticsearch

I have several indices with different fields, and while a request containing just a search query yields the expected results, I get no hits when I combine the query with a `suggest` part which does not work for the index containing the hit (because the field references in the `suggest` is not present there).

**Edit:** That I do not get any suggestions for an index is not really a problem, but I was hoping there was a way to make sure that I still get result for the `query` part even if the `suggestion` part fails.

The actual query in question is a `multi_match` across several fields an quite complex, but I could reproduce my problem with the following example.

1. Create two indices with different fields

   ```
   PUT /test1
   {
       "mappings": {
           "default": {
               "properties": {
                   "field1": {
                       "type": "text"
                   }
               }
           }
       }
   }

   PUT /test2
   {
       "mappings": {
           "default": {
               "properties": {
                   "field2": {
                       "type": "text"
                   }
               }
           }
       }
   }
   ```
2. Add something to the indices

   ```
   PUT /test1/default?refresh=true
   {
       "field1": "DEADBEEF in index 1"
   }

   PUT /test2/default?refresh=true
   {
       "field2": "FOOBARDOO in index 2"
   }
   ```
3. Searching for `FOOBARD` in `field2` yields the expected result from index `test2`

   ```
   POST /_search
   {
       "query": {
           "match": {
               "field2": {
                   "query": "FOOBARD",
                   "fuzziness": 2
               }
           }
       }
   }
   ```
4. But when I add the `suggest` to the query

   ```
    {
       "query": {
           "match": {
               "field2": {
                   "query": "FOOBARD",
                   "fuzziness": 2
               }
           }
       },
       "suggest": {
           "text": "FOOBARD",
           "suggest-field1": {
               "term": {
                   "field": "field1"
               }
           }
       }
   }
   ```

   I get a failure message about the missing mapping, and zero search hits:

   ```
   {
       ...
       "_shards": {
           ...
           "failures": [
               {
                   "shard": 0,
                   "index": "test2",
                   "node": "TGUboSt9SweF3KQBKnoVSg",
                   "reason": {
                       "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
                       "reason": "no mapping found for field [field1]"
                   }
               }
           ]
       },
       "hits": {
           "total": 0,
           "max_score": null,
           "hits": []
       },
       ...
   }
   ```

Is this expected behaviour when looking for suggestions over multiple indices, or am I doing something wrong here? I would like to avoid making two queries, which would differ just in the suggestion part.

Any hints and pointers are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is expected behavior. Suggest expects field mapping to be present in all indices queried against.

Here is relevant [source code](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/master/server/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/search/suggest/SuggestionBuilder.java#L307) ( Not sure if its in manual )

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My problem is less the failing of the suggestion, but that I also get no search hits for that index. Since I _do_ get hits from other indices (where the suggestion does not fail), I was hoping there was a way to prevent a failed suggestion to break the entire search on that index.

It seams there is no other way, than to separate the `query` and the `suggestion` parts.